# Extend Integer given conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to extend IDs with a number, e.g. 007.
But only in the event that `GRP = 3` occurs in an `ID`. Then only the rows for these IDs should be changed where `GRP != 3` and `DAT IS NULL`.

The data is available in this form

| ID | DAT | GRP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 3 |
| 1 | *null* | 1 |
| 1 | *null* | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | 3 |
| 2 | *null* | 2 |
| 3 | *null* | 1 |
| 3 | *null* | 1 |

I expect the following

| ID | DAT | GRP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 3 |
| 1007 | *null* | 1 |
| 1007 | *null* | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | 3 |
| 2007 | *null* | 2 |
| 3 | *null* | 1 |
| 3 | *null* | 1 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yHr3hF0y)

My approach which just adds 007. So for ID 1 the new ID is 8 instead of 1007. Further, ID 3 is missing due to the `WHERE EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
  WHEN DAT IS NULL AND GRP != 3 THEN ID + 007 ELSE ID END AS ID_NEW
  FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t2
              WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
              AND GRP = 3
             )
```

Result of my approach

| ID | DAT | GRP | ID_NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | *null* | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | *null* | 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 200 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | *null* | 2 | 9 |

Thank you very much for your support

Comment: So what's stopping you? What is the difficulty you have having achieving your goal.

Comment: id * 1000 +7?..

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you! Works fine. That easy. Now the Problem is that ID 3 is excluded with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(t.ID, '007') ELSE t.ID END AS ID, DAT, GRP
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM table1
  WHERE GRP = 3
) AS s on s.ID = t.ID AND GRP != 3 and DAT IS NULL;
```

Results :

```
ID      DAT     GRP
1       100     3
1007    null    1
1007    null    1
2       200     3
2007    null    2
3       null    1
3       null    1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sk3h966Y)